# Getting Xdebug Working with MAMP and Mac

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

So been at this for a bit and thought someone here might be able to help me.

So I am using a MAMP stack on mac. I think I have the PHP interpreter sorted out well:

[image]

So that is the link to my php executable and I changed my php.ini to:

[image]

And everything seems pretty good thus the `'Debugger: Xdebug 2.2.7`' in the first pic.

I also downloaded the chrome JetBrains plugin so when I go to debug Chrome gets launched:

[image]

When I try to debug

[image]

I have no idea why it is skipping the breakpoint but I have never debugged with Phpstorm or php for that matter
(usually just use print_r, var_dump... but I really would like to get this working).

I did the Web Server Debug Validation and I ended up with:

[image]

This looks like it should be at least to me.

In the debugging window it looks like:

[image]

But no variables are listed and the stack is empty.

I'm not sure what I am missing it seems like something simple since Phpstorm is screaming at me some errors.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains Chrome Extension is meant to be the connection between the browser and IDE.

What you want, ist PHP and IDE to be connected.

It seems to me than what you are missing is to tell phpStrom to listen to that Xdebug connection. You can do so by clicking the phone receiver icon.

BTW, you don’t need to edit php.ini, the option to activate Xdebug is also available from MAMP (PRO?) options. But maybe that is possible in PRO only.

Answer (score 0):

Find `[xdebug]` inside your php.ini configuration file and add these 2 lines before `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`

```
 xdebug.remote_autostart=1     
 xdebug.remote_enable=On
```

Restart your localhost and PHPStorm.